# Android application statistics

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

Is there an API for application statistics: number of installations, number of downloads, active apps, etc.?

Also is there a way to know the number of the buyer? Meaning - a user was the "799th buyer" of a certain app.

Comment: I don't know if there's an external API but installation information is pretty well available on publisher console on Android Market. When it comes to paying customers I do not know how it shows though - if at all.

Comment: There is an app named AndLytics that shows you all data. What do they use?

Comment: Ah, didn't know of such application. Anyway. I gave it a quick go and first thing AndLytics asks is your developer account (which it says is required). So I'm guessing they harness information from default www-based publish console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use API in Android, but Activities. If you are interested in info from Market, you should use the appropriate Activity from Market.